# How to establish relationship between dot product of vectors in two different form

Tags: vectors, inner-products

If $ \vec{a} = a_1 \hat{i} + a_2 \hat{j} + a_3 \hat{k} $ and $ \vec{b} = b_1 \hat{i} + b_2 \hat{j} + b_3 \hat{k} $ are two vectors, there dot products have two different forms

> (i)
> $ \vec{a}.\vec{b} = \mid a \mid \times \mid b \mid cos \space \theta $

> (ii)
> $ \vec{a} . \vec{b} = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3b_3 $

How can we prove that these two are the same? **How can we prove it in 3 dimensional XYZ space?**

Comment: Cf. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Equivalence_of_the_definitions)

Comment: Is there a geometrical proof for 3D ? for example in case of 2D, a.b = a1b1+a2b2 = |a|cos(m)|b|cos(n) + |a|sin(m)|b|sin(n) = |a|.|b| [ cos(m)cos(n) + sin(m)sin(n) ] = |a|.|b| cos(m-n) = |a| . |b| cos (t) where t = m-n = angle between vec a and vec b so a.b = |a|.|b| cos(t)

Answer (score 1):

Consider vectors $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.  Define vector $\vec{c}$ as

$ \vec{c} = \vec{b} - \vec{a} $

Vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ form the three sides of a triangle in $3D$. Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$.

And let's define the inner (dot) product between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ as follows:

$ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + a_3 b_3 $

Then

$ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 = a^2 $

And similarly, $\vec{b} \cdot \vec{b} = b^2 $, and $\vec{c} \cdot \vec{c} = c^2$

Therefore, applying the law of cosines to the triangle, on the one hand we have,

$ (\vec{b} - \vec{a}) \cdot (\vec{b} - \vec{a} ) = c^2 =  a^2 + b^2 - 2 a b \cos \theta $

And on the other hand, we have

$ (\vec{b} - \vec{a}) \cdot (\vec{b} - \vec{a} )  = \vec{b} \cdot \vec{b} + \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} - 2 \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} $

Comparing the two expressions, we deduce that

$ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = a b \cos \theta $